# Having trouble creating my Neural Network inputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently working on a neural network that should have N parameters in input. Each parameters can have M different values (discrete values), let's say {A,B,C,…,M}. It also has a discrete number of outputs.

How can I create my inputs from this situation? Should I have N×M inputs (having 0 or 1 as value), or should I think of a different approach?

Answer (score 2):

The concept is very similar to that. However, as the outputs are probabilities, each column of $M$ outputs should sum to $1$.

Therefore, having your $NxM$ target matrix, you could use $N$ softmax functions on their $M$ outputs, in order to make each column sum to $1$.

There are many approaches to do that, depending on where you are implementing this. I usually prefer Torch7, which is considered the state-of-the-art in neural networks and is supported by NYU, Google Deepmind and Facebook AI.